# Alternative for hybrid web app without knowledge in app/server

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

i used to upload my ZIP (with HTML5/CSS web app) in phonegap since 4, 5 years and create cool mobile apps. But since some months it's look like Adobe dismiss the project, no more answer on forum etc.

Is there a good solution, when you don't know everything about shift/cocoa/java and server things, to simply upload your webapp (basically a website in a zip) and get IPA/APK ?

I heard about monaco or voltbuilder. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. Although I can confirm https://build.phonegap.com works for me. If you have an error related to a malformed xml, you can try to delete the project on the website and re-uplading the zip file onto a new project. That's a bug I have experienced in the past.

Otherwise, you can install Cordova and Phonegap on your pc to build it using npm on the terminal (Linux/MacOs).

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova
```

or for windows (CMD):

```
C:\> npm install -g cordova
```

then navigate with the command line using cd to go to a folder
eg. `cd myfolder`.
You can see the files in your current directory with `ls` (Linux/MacOs) or `lsdir` (windows)

Once you are in your project's folder and that you can see with `lsdir` or `ls` your config.xml file of your project, then you can run those commands to add the platform you want to build:

```
cordova platform add ios
cordova platform add android
```

Finally to build the app, you need to:

```
cordova build
```

Note: To build an Ipa, you will need to use a device running MacOs since it requires XCode. I highly recommand you to get familiar with Cmd or the terminal if you are building an app.

I hope I have answered your question well